# Jenkins - Distribute same job to different slaves

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

We do have a master Jenkin server and 4 slaves. Each slaves has 2 executors. We sometimes need to run the same job concurrently. Ie: run 4 x "Stage Build" at the same time.

Problem is, Jenkins tries to run the job on the last slave that it was run on. If we run the same job concurrently then server 1 and 2 will run 2 jobs each, which we do not want to. We want each server to run only 1 "Stage Build".

Any suggestion how can we archive that? Thanks

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin provides a configuration option that tells Jenkins not to run two copies of this job on the same slave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Throttle concurrent builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) plugin:

- Install the plugin
- Go to Job configuration
- Enable "Execute concurrent builds if necessary"
- Enable "Throttle Concurrent Builds"
- Set "Maximum Total Concurrent Builds=4"
- Set "Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node=1"
- Enable "Restrict where this project can be run" and in the Label Expression add your label for the 4 slaves

Good luck!